# Appending a value to a nested QList

Tags: c++, qt, append, push-back, qlist

I am trying to append values to a `QList` inside another `QList` but it doesn't seem to work?

Here is a MCVE of my problem where I try to append int values:

```
#include <QList>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    QList<QList<int>> my_list;

    int result;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
            result = i * j;
            my_list.value(i).push_back(result);
            qDebug() << my_list.size() << "," << my_list.value(i).size() << " : " << my_list.value(i).value(j);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This yields:

```
Starting C:\Users\ ... \build\release\name_of_the_app.exe...
0 , 0  :  0
0 , 0  :  0
0 , 0  :  0
0 , 0  :  0
0 , 0  :  0
0 , 0  :  0
0 , 0  :  0
0 , 0  :  0
C:\Users\ ... \build\release\name_of_the_app.exe exited with code 0
```

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with this code sample:

**First:**

The container `my_list` hasn't been initialised yet. The line

```
my_list.value(i).push_back(result);
```

doesn't actually push values into the container (as we might have hoped).

In your code, `i` is always out of bounds. (Since `my_list` will always have size 0.) As a result, and according to the [*documentation*](http://doc.qt.io//qt-5/qlist.html#value),

> If the index i is out of bounds, the function returns a [default-constructed value](http://doc.qt.io//qt-5/containers.html#default-constructed-value).

Since this *default-constructed value* isn't assigned anywhere, it will most probably be allocated on the heap and be left sitting there until destructed.

Further accesses into `my_list` such as `qDebug() << my_list.value(i).size()` will default-construct another QList (since again, `i` is out of bounds).

Make sure you already have `QList<int>` ready to push values into.

**Second:**

The `value()` method returns a const reference to the QList which does not allow modification (same for `at()`).  If you want to push values to a QList you should use the `[]` instead of the `value()` method.

The following code does what you want:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    my_list.push_back(QList<int>());   // first appends a new QList at index `i`

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
        result = i * j;
        my_list[i].push_back(result);  // safely retrieves QList at index `i` and adds an element
    }
}
```

Comment: There where two issues with my code. Your answer addressed the first (major) issue (thanks!) and allowed me to further correct my code. I added it to your answer as an edit.

Comment: I've approved the edit.  Didn't realise `.value()` didn't provide a reference. I usually only use `[]` and `.at()`. :-)